# form binding: relationship with intermediate entity (nested entity) - indirect Entity creation and binding

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

My simplified model looks like this:

```
@Entity public class Aspect extends Model {
    @Id public Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) public List<Restriction> restrictions;
}

@Entity public class Restriction extends Model {
    @Id public Integer id;
    @ManyToOne public RestrictionTemplate restrictionTemplate;
}

@Entity public class RestrictionTemplate extends Model {
    @Id private Integer id;
}
```

Basically the idea is this: each **Aspect** has a set of **Restrictions**. And each **Restriction** itself relies on a **RestrictionTemplate**.

I want **Aspect** creation form to like this: user can select some **RestrictionTemplates** and on form submit new **Restrictions** should be created and associated with new **Aspect**.

**Let me explain once again:** On form submission I want to create **Aspect** and relating **Restrictions** based on **RestrictionTemplate's** ids provided.

Whicn names should the fields in the form have in order to make such binding possible?

The naming which works for direct relantionships:

```
restrictions[0].restrictionTemplate.id
restrictions[1].restrictionTemplate.id
```

doesn't work here (creates **Aspect** entry in DB, but no **Restriction** entries).

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply must write a bit of code for that, in which you search for the `RestrictionTemplates` corresponding to the passed IDs and then assigning them to the new instance of `Aspect`:

```
List<RestrictionTemplates> templates = new ArrayList<RestrictionTemplates>();
for (int crtTplId : passedIds) {
    templates.add(entityManager.find(RestrictionTemplates.class, crtTplId));
}


List<Restriction> restrictions = new ArrayList<Restriction>();
for (RestrictionTemplates crtTpl : templates) {
    restrictions.add(new Restriction(crtTpl));
}

Aspect aspect = new Aspect();
aspect.restrictions = restrictions;

entityManager.persist(aspect);
```

PS: as I understand, there can be Restrictions that do not belong to an Aspect. If that is not true, than you should make your Aspect-Restriction relationship bilateral, `Restriction` being the owning side:

```
@Entity public class Aspect extends Model {
    @Id public Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="aspect") public List<Restriction> restrictions;
}

@Entity public class Restriction extends Model {
    @Id public Integer id;
    @OneToMany(/*+ add the @JoinColumn for marking the column not nullable*/) public Aspect aspect;
    @ManyToOne public RestrictionTemplate restrictionTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! I can obviously do that. But I want binding to be done automatically by Play when I'm following field' naming convention. According to this question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/nested$20binding/play-framework/CukNF9kV_uU/NcelALWPnOAJ Play can bind OneToMany -> OneToMany nested models from field named as "client.customers[0].address[0].zipcode". I wonder how to make binding work in my case (OneToMany -> ManyToOne).